# Убрать у всех class="active"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как на js можно у всех `li` которые в `ul` убрать класс `active`, есть идея реализации в цикле пройтись и проверить наличие класса и убрать, но не думаю что лучшее решение, как правильнее сделать?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active" id="1" ><a href="/" >9</a></li>
  <li class="active" id="2" ><a href="/" >8</a></li>
  <li class="active" id="3" ><a href="/" >7</a></li>
  <li id="4" ><a href="/" >6</a></li>
  <li class="active" id="5" ><a href="/">5</a></li>
  <li id="6" ><a href="/" >4</a></li>
  <li class="active" id="7"  ><a href="/" >3</a></li>
  <li id="8" ><a href="/" >2 </a></li>
  <li class="active" id="9" ><a href="/" >1</a></li>
 </ul>
```

P.s. `active` может отсутствовать у некоторых элементов как выше в 8, 6, 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще всего это сделать вот так:

```
$('ul li.active').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: Добавил `ul` `id="menu"` и сделал так `$('#menu li.active').removeClass('active');` , спасибо! Отмечу правильным после 7 минут :) просто нельзя